# Creating a pagination

Tags: jquery, html, pagination

I have a huge amount of div's all being displayed on this one page (roughly 25 right now) and every day more and more are getting added. I was wondering if there is an easy to use jQuery library to utilize pagination or if there is a very simple script that I can write to go about breaking these up without manually making all the extra pages. Here's my HTML (very basic and simple). Maybe even using an Ajax method? I'm not very familiar with writing Ajax though, which is why I've come here

```
<section class="stories">
  <h2>The Stories</h2>

  <div class="story">
      <h4>Title</h4>
      <p>Story info</p>
  </div>

  <div class="story">
      <h4>Title</h4>
      <p>Story info</p>
  </div>

  <div class="story">
      <h4>Title</h4>
      <p>Story info</p>
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Creating a pagination feature for you now, should be around 5 minutes

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're using tabular data, in which case a table might be the best approach. Since you're not extremely familiar with the process anyhow, there's absolutely zero reasons to not use a library.

I'd highly recommend [DataTables.js](http://www.datatables.net/).

Comment: There's not really any reason to use a table with this information since all it is is a title and then the story. Is there a better library that focuses on just Pagination?

Comment: That's a neat library and does what I'm looking for, but this table would look awful with all the stories having different lengths. I just can't picture a table working with this layout

Comment: @user3532666 yeah, they're several pagination libraries, lolka_bolka's answer provides a link to a list of some. I'd still recommend looking at a table for this. Unless you plan on having an  unordered list.

Answer (score 1):

Very rough version, but I don't have much time and the core workings are there, one or two ajustments such as range validation need to be added but it should work nethertheless.

```
var start = 0;
var ending = 5;
var jump = 5;
var count = 0;
var stories = $('.story');
function paginate() {
    stories.show();
    $.each(stories, function() {
        if(count > ending && count < start) {
            $(this).hide();
        }
        count++;
    });
}

$('#next').on('click', function() {
    start += jump;
    ending += jump;
    paginate();
});

$('#prev').on('click', function() {
    start -= jump;
    ending -= jump;
    paginate();
});

paginate();
```

Comment: If someone could take five minutes to edit this so it is fool proof that would be much appreciated !!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not a big work to write one for yourself. I've never met a library or plugin like this, but take a shot: http://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-pagination-plugins/

What i think, this can be done like this:

Need the number of items to show.
Need the number of items.
Need how many page do you have.
Need the current page.

Store the number of items what you want to show into a variable.
Count, how many items do you have.
Check the url, is there a paramter like `pageNum` or anything, what tells you, what is the current page.
With the division of `maxpage / itemsonpage` rounded up will gives you, how many page do you have.
With the current page and itemsonpate you can calculate the start point.

And you can use hases to store, what is the current page.